# MVC avoid page load if on the same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

if the UrlReferrer same as the Url that is about to load. How do I avoid page reload?
example User is on About page and clicks on the About menu item. I want to do nothing.

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {           

        if (Request.Url == HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "same: "+ DateTime.Now;
            //return ???
        }
        else {
            ViewBag.Message = "new: "+ DateTime.Now;
            return View();
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom action and make your link point to this, like:

```
public ActionResult RedirectToAbout()
{
}
```

In this, check for the current address, if its same as about then do nothing, else redirect.

```
if (currentControllerName.Equals("SomeController", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                                                currentActionName.Equals("About", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
//Do Nothing
}
else
{
//Redirect here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this in your menu, not on the server. So, when you land on the home page, your menu partial view (or your master page, depending on where the menu is) should know that the URL of the Home menu item should be removed and changed to a "javascript:return false;" or something to that effect.